# xamarin android webview: video not playing on device

Tags: android, video, webview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Trying to play a video, I am using a WebView inside of Xamarin.Forms XAML right now.

I have great problems on Android (this being a forms project, it also runs on iOS and WinPhone), mainly with playing local files.

To get to a minimal failing version, I saw that even playing videos from the web does not work. Oh, and it (kind of - at least I get audio) works in the emulator, but not on my device, which is a Samsung Note 1.

What I am doing is

```
var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
html = "<!Doctype HTML><html><body><video controls>   <source src=\"http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm\" type=\"video/webm\">   <source src=\"http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv\" type=\"video/ogg\">   <source src=\"http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4\" type=\"video/mp4\">  <source src=\"http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp\" type=\"video/3gp\"></video></body></html>";
htmlSource.Html = html;
myWebView.Source = htmlSource;
```

The html is directly copied (only formatting and "" added) from http://techslides.com/sample-webm-ogg-and-mp4-video-files-for-html5 .

In the AndroidManifest.xml I added

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

to the

```
<manifest />
```

(I also tried *false*.)

What I see on Android device:

Website opens, shows video controls (though only on very small area, it has a placeholder background). Clicking play, I get a "handleMessage - PLAY" in the debugger, but nothing happens. Also, clicking the fullscreen icon, I get a "enterFullScreenVideoState called." in the debugger, but nothing happens.

Additional:
Opening http://techslides.com/sample-webm-ogg-and-mp4-video-files-for-html5 directly in the Android-browser works (I don't get a preview of the video, but it loads when I click on play), but setting

```
myWebView.Source = "http://techslides.com/sample-webm-ogg-and-mp4-video-files-for-html5";
```

also produces the same bad behavior as when I explicitly set the HtmlWebViewSource.

App has INTERNET permission.

What is wrong, how to fix?

(I know there are a lot of threads on this on stackoverflow, but many are 3-5 years old, and none apply to Xamarin, at least not from what I have seen so far.)

Comment: Did you ever figure out an answer for this? [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/138605/#Comment_138605) is a post explaining the issue with Xamarin Android WebView's and playing videos and [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/63713/#Comment_63713) is a post explaining a possible solution it the problem for Xamarin Forms.

Comment: Not really. Part of the problem was the mobile phone, a galaxy note 1. I remember it working better on other makes. Also I tried Cordova (via Intel XDK) later on and had similar issues. I did stop though after spending a couple of days on it.

Comment: Well I appreciate the update nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play the video in a native player instead of launching a WebView, you can check out the video player component on the Xamarin component store. It allows you to render the native video player on iOS, Android, and Windows Phone. The code snippet below shows the simplest example of just dropping it in and using it. You also have the ability to hook into events like playing, paused, stopped, completed, etc. You can control volume, autoplay, and repeat among other things.

https://github.com/adamfisher/Xamarin.Forms.VideoPlayer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:o="clr-namespace:Octane.Xam.VideoPlayer;assembly=Octane.Xam.VideoPlayer"
             x:Class="VideoPlayerSamples.VideoPlayerBasicExamplePage"
             Title="Basic Video Player">

    <o:VideoPlayer Source="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" />

</ContentPage>
```

**Disclaimer:** This is my component.